# how to draw a line knowing the starting coordinate, line length x angle and y, angle

Tags: python, math, computer-vision, geometry, drawing

I am trying to draw a line knowing the starting coordinate, line length x angle and y, angle. I am trying to visualize the eye gaze direction of a human in a video.

For an example, I want to draw the blue lines here:

[image]

I already have the center point of the eye (start of the blue line), and I already have the x and y angle of the eye. How do I draw this line?

I've found a lot of tutorials on how to draw such lines (https://learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/), but they involve translation and rotation vectors. Is there a clean way to do this just using the known x/y angles?

Comment: What is an x angle and a y angle?  Do you mean the components of the rotation angle? An angle is just one value, not two.  Please define your terms. See last answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143932/calculate-point-given-x-y-angle-and-distance

Comment: I must be confused. I think I do mean the components of the rotation angle. What I mean by x (I think) is the rotation angle over the y axis (y axis being a vertical line going down the center of the eye) and y is the rotation al over the x axis (x axis being a horizontal line through the center of the eye.

Comment: Those two should be the same. Please draw a diagram showing what you want for the two angles and why they are different? Do you mean the x and y components (i.e. r*cos(angle) and r*sin(angle) which are distances not angles.

Comment: @fmw42 It is already solved. He explained what he means in a comment below my answer, in case you didn't notice.

Comment: @Confused Learner. OK. But your answer is just what I posted above in the link to math.stachexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a length r and an angle φ between the x-axis and your line to draw, you can calculate a coordinate for a point P(x, y) like this:

x = r * cos(φ)

y = r * sin(φ)

For example, a vertical line with r = 1; φ = 90° = π / 2 would return y = 1 * sin(π / 2) = 1

Then you can import your image in `opencv` and draw a line using [`cv2.line`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-line-method/).

Comment: I must be confused. I think I mean the components of the rotation angle. What I mean by x (I think) is the rotation angle over the y axis (y axis being a vertical line going down the center of the eye) and y is the rotation al over the x axis (x axis being a horizontal line through the center of the eye. Does this make sense or am I confusing things futher?

Comment: You don't need the x angle. The y angle = φ should work for all cases.

Comment: Why don't I need the x angle? If the eyes look up or down, isn't this rotation over the x-axis? And if the eyes look left or right, isn't this rotation over the y-axis?

Comment: [This](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-interactive-unit-circle.html) interactive plot should help. As you can see, you only need the angle between the x-axis and the line. You can use positive and negative values: 270° = -90° And remember that functions like `math.sin` expect your value to be in radians.

Answer (score 1):

[image: no that not drawn with paint]

It’s basically just math:

As far as I know, the height of the triangle is `height = math.sinus(h) * l` and its width is `width = math.cos(h) * l`.
I hope this help.